# Developing android applications using Xamarin Vs Native android

Tags: c#, android

Does anybody know to give me a comparison of advantages and disadvantages in programming through C# in Xamarin Versus Android java native code?

Is developing through Xamarin is way more limited than native android, or the gap is not that far.
I would like to hear opinion from someone who has experience in developing with **both** technologies.
Thanks

Comment: I understand this is an opinion based question, BUT its a very valid one. Its one A TON of folks have. I answer this question a lot at conferences.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

***Update*** 20160822: This advice still holds true. I continually am asked about this. One company I know of went with Xamarin only to find out that it did not solve their Android problems as they had to learn both languages/implementations to solve most their issues.

***Update*** 20150513: Thus far, this is one of the most asked questions I get from startups. Which way should they go. I inevitably end up pointing them to this post. It is still solid advice.

I've developed with both. You can pretty much do whatever you want in Xamarin. The couple of difficult areas you're going to run into are:

- Finding good, working example code. Edge cases are really the bummer here.
- You'll find that you end up learning Java through Xamarin because you have to read so much Java code.

Another problem is that while Xamarin is doing well and is gaining traction, the community is still rather small. This poses a problem when you release a Xamarin app. If you need to bring in someone else to maintain it, they have to know .NET, C# and Android. Finding that combo is rather difficult and I've found that all the contractors or consultants that I needed to update my app were VERY expensive.

Thats the hidden gotcha. It will help you get out the door faster, but up keep and new feature development will cost you, IF you're NOT the one doing the updates.

Why do I know this? I've written two apps with Xamarin that I eventually wanted updated. I had to contact a contractor to do it because I simply didnt have the time. It was quite expensive compared to Android or iOS devs that were already out there. I ended up moving those apps from Xamarin to Native Android and iOS.

That aside. Its a freaking awesome platform. If you plan to always work on it, then use it. Being able to use the power of C# is great. After working with C# for many years I've grown to really have a disdain for Java. Thats personal preference, but it is what it is.

Its all about tradeoffs.

Comment: Great answer thanks. How troublesome was it to convert to native Android? I'll be doing the initial development and big pivots, then getting other developers involved. So I'm tempted by starting in Xamarin then converting, partly as I'm C# fluent, and partly as MVVMCross, Task Parallel Library, etc seem able to reduce code volume. In my case business logic will be complex, but so will rendering to surfaces, animation and custom gestures (I'll use minimal native controls).

Comment: @Chris For me, converting to Android was easy. Disclaimer - I've written a few books on Android Development - so things are a little different for me. It really depends on the level of complexity that your app has ...

Comment: can you please give links to your apps which you have created with xamarin??

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi They are no longer written in Xamarin so it would be an unfair comparison to post them now (I've had them ported over to native iOS and Android).